How to modify an animation made with the animate package with (external) JavaScript?
The documentation of the animate package states in chapter 7, on page 15:

The package provides a simple JavaScript programming interface which gives access
to the animation objects in a PDF ﬁle. A particular animation property or method can
be accessed by
anim[’<anim label>’].<property or method>
or 
anim.<anim label>.<property or method>
anim is an array of animation object references. Animations must be labelled using
the label=... command option in order to be present in the anim array. As usual,
properties and methods are accessed via the dot notation.

I have tried internal JavaScript (embedded in the PDF/svg) as well as external JavaScript (svg opened directly in browser with debug shell, svg wrapped in html) and could not get it to work.
MWE
Consider the following MWE based upon my previous question and an answer given by AlexG, that displays a simple "Hello World!" animation.
\documentclass[dvisvgm, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{luacode*}
    function animateText(currentTime, currentFrame, timeToStart, text, frameRate, charSpeed)
        startFrame = math.floor(timeToStart * frameRate)
        if currentTime >= timeToStart then
            idx = math.floor((currentFrame - startFrame)*(charSpeed/frameRate))
            if idx>0 then
                tex.sprint(string.sub(text, 1, idx))
            end
            if idx <= string.len(text) then
                tex.sprint("\\makebox[0pt]{|}")
            end
        end
    end
\end{luacode*}

\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
    \special{dvisvgm:raw%
        <style>svg{cursor: none}</style>%
        <defs>%
        <script type="text/javascript">%
        <![CDATA[%
        console.log("Test print in console from within PDF/svg");% <- works fine
        % anything else like document.anim["HelloWorld"], document.anim.HelloWorld
        % document.getElementById()... fails, even if wrapped in the load() event
        % IDEALLY: Modify animation here!
        ]]>%
        </script>%
        </defs>%
    }%
}%

\def\frameRate{30}
\def\animationDuration{6} % in seconds

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\frameTime}{(60/\frameRate) * 0.00833 * 2}
    
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}%
    \begin{frame}%
        \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop, label=HelloWorld]{60}%
            \multiframe{\directlua{tex.sprint(\animationDuration * \frameRate)}}{rt=0+\frameTime, iframeNumber=0+1}{%
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \useasboundingbox (-\textwidth/2,-\textheight/2)rectangle++(\textwidth,\textheight);%
                    \fill[green](-2.5,-2.5)rectangle++(5,5);%
                    \node[text=white, font=\Huge, minimum width=5cm] at (0,0){%
                        \strut%
                        \directlua{animateText(\rt, \iframeNumber, 0, "Hello World!", \frameRate, 5)}%
                    };%
                \end{tikzpicture}%
            }%
        \end{animateinline}%
    \end{frame} %

    \begin{frame}
        After the animation ended, the next beamer frame is automatically loaded. 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

After compiling this with dvilualatex mwe and converting it via
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 --output=./%f_%0p.svg mwe.dvi

to svg, the result is the following:

Questions
Even though the documentation of the animate package lists all the available parameters and functions which can be accessed via JavaScript, I could not get it working.

How is it possible to:
a) change to the next beamer frame when the animation has finished (preferably with JavaScript)?
b) trigger another event at a certain time/progress of the animation (preferably with JavaScript)?
Might there be an issue due to the conversion with dvisvgm into svg?
Long term goal: Embed svg into html. Some sources I looked at stated that external modifications of a svg embedded in html is not possible (others said it is possible if the svg is loaded from the same domain). Any experience with/thoughts on that?


Answering questions in reverse order.
A 3 (long-term goal)
Animated SVG made with pkg animate can be embedded into HTML with the <iframe> tag and controlled from the parent document with JavaScript. It requires the parent HTML and the SVG file to be loaded from the same domain. In order to work locally, a web server needs to be set up.
Interactive example:

The animation object anim inside the SVG is reached from the parent document's JavaScript via the contentWindow property of the iframe element "hello":
anim = document.getElementById("hello").contentWindow.anim;

Animation TeX source (example.tex), typeset to SVG with
dvilualatex example
dvilualatex example
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --exact --zoom=-1 --output=texsx-732425-anim.svg example

\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{luacode*}
  function createNodeText(idx, text)
    if idx>0 then
      tex.sprint(string.sub(text, 1, idx))
    end
    if idx <= string.len(text) then
      tex.sprint("\\makebox[0pt]{|}")
    end
  end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\animText{"Hello World!"}

\begin{document}
  \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,label=helloworld]{5}
     \multiframe{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len(\animText)+5)}}{idx=0+1}{
       \begin{tikzpicture}
         \useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2.5)rectangle++(5,5);
         \fill[green](-2.5,-2.5)rectangle++(5,5);
         \node[font=\Huge] at (0,0){\strut\directlua{createNodeText(\idx, \animText)}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
     }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}

Parent HTML document:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script>
    var anim;
    <!-- when page is ready, get reference to SVG internal `anim' object -->
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      anim = document.getElementById("hello").contentWindow.anim;
    });
  </script>
<head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h3>Embedded SVG animation with external controls</h3>

    <!-- iframe `hello' running the animated SVG -->
    <iframe id="hello" width="300" height="300" src="./texsx-732425-anim.svg" frameborder="1"></iframe><br>

    <button onclick="anim['helloworld'].stopFirst()">Rewind</button>
    <button onclick="if(anim['helloworld'].isPlaying) anim['helloworld'].pause(); else anim['helloworld'].playFwd();">Play/Pause</button>
    <button onclick="try {anim['helloworld'].frameNum++} catch(e) {anim['helloworld'].frameNum=0}">Step</button>
  </center>
</body>

</html>

A 1a, 1b
For this kind of event-triggered JavaScript actions, a timeline file can be associated with the animation.
A timeline file defines the order at which each included graphic is to appear in an animation. It allows graphics to be repeated and overlaid and also JavaScript to be triggered at given points in time. Each line in a timeline file represents a frame of the animation. Refer to the manual for the exact syntax.
Here, by means of JavaScript, an alert box is shown when the animation starts, and the SVG with the next presentation slide is loaded into the web browser when the animation ends. The last graphic with the complete string is repeated a few times before that happens.
The timeline file is written in a \multido loop, but could as well be written manually or by means of the filecontents environment. It should look like this:
::0:window.alert("This is the beginning of the animation.")
::1
::2
::3
::4
::5
::6
::7
::8
::9
::10
::11
::12
::12
::12
::12
::12
::12:document.location.replace('texsx-732425-2.svg')

A bit of code was added that implements buttons and keyboard and mouse interaction to navigate between presentation slides.
Click to run example (Firefox v130+ required); press [F11] for full-screen:

Typeset with
dvilualatex example
dvilualatex example
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize --page=1- --linkmark=none exmple

\documentclass[dvisvgm, hypertex, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% slide navigation via keyboard and mouse left-or-right-click/mouse wheel,
% mouse cursor autohide on idle; navigation symbols <--, -->
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\AddToHook{shipout/before}{\xdef\currentPageNumber{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1}}}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
  \put(0,0){%
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \normalsize\color{structure!40!}%
      \ifnum\currentPageNumber>1%
        \href{\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber-1\relax}.svg}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \fi\hspace{0.5ex}%
      \ifnum\currentPageNumber<\PreviousTotalPages%
        \href{\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber+1\relax}.svg}{\faArrowRight}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowRight}%
      \fi%
      \hspace{0.5ex}%
    }}%
  }%
  \special{dvisvgm:raw
    <style>svg{cursor: none}</style>%
    <defs>%
    <script type="text/javascript">%
    <![CDATA[%
      var cursorTimer;%
      var downOnLink=false;%
      var downOnRoot=false;%
      function islink(tg){return (tg.tagName=='a') ? true : tg.parentNode ? islink(tg.parentNode) : false;};%
      function ismmedia(tg){return (tg.tagName=='video'||tg.tagName=='audio') ? true : tg.parentNode ? ismmedia(tg.parentNode) : false;};%
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){%
        if(islink(e.target)||ismmedia(e.target)||e.target.getAttribute('class')=='annot'){%
          e.target.style.cursor='pointer';}else{e.target.style.cursor='default';}%
        try{clearTimeout(cursorTimer);}catch(err){};%
        cursorTimer=setTimeout(function(){e.target.style.cursor='none';},3000);%
      });%
      window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){% capture right click
        if(!islink(e.target)&&!ismmedia(e.target)) e.preventDefault();%
      });%
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){%
        if(islink(e.target)||ismmedia(e.target)) downOnLink=true;%
        else downOnRoot=true;%
      });%
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){%
        if(downOnLink||!downOnRoot){downOnLink=false;return;}%
        downOnRoot=false;%
        \ifnum\currentPageNumber<\PreviousTotalPages
          if(!e.shiftKey&&e.button==0) document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber+1\relax}.svg');%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\currentPageNumber>1
          if(e.shiftKey||e.button>1) document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber-1\relax}.svg');%
        \fi%
      });%
      document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){%
        \ifnum\currentPageNumber<\PreviousTotalPages
          if(e.deltaY>0){%
            document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber+1\relax}.svg');%
          }%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\currentPageNumber>1
          if(e.deltaY<0){%
            document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber-1\relax}.svg');%
          }%
        \fi%
      });%
      document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){%
          \ifnum\currentPageNumber<\PreviousTotalPages
            if(e.key=='PageDown'||e.key=='ArrowDown'||e.key=='ArrowRight')%
                document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber+1\relax}.svg');%
          \fi%
          \ifnum\currentPageNumber>1
            if(e.key=='PageUp'||e.key=='ArrowUp'||e.key=='ArrowLeft')%
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber-1\relax}.svg');%
          \fi%
          if(e.key=='Home')
            document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{1}.svg');%
          if(e.key=='End')
            document.location.replace('\jobname-\PreviousTotalPages.svg');%
        });%
    ]]>%
    </script>%
    </defs>%
  }%
}%
% helper macro \zeroPad : zero-pads integer according to template,
% e. g. 123 --> 00123 if template is `99999`
% #1: arbitrary integer number as template specifying the
%     width, e. g. `987654' for a width of 6 digits
% #2: the number to be formatted
\def\zeroPad#1#2{\zeroPadI{\zeroTemplate{0}{#1}}{#2}}
%low level macros used by \zeroPad
\def\zeroPadI#1#2{% #1: string of zeros specifying width, #2 number
  \ifnum1#2<1#1
    \zeroPadI{#1}{0#2}%
  \else%
    #2%
  \fi%
}%
\def\zeroTemplate#1#2{% create template (string of zeros) from given num
  \ifnum10#1>1#2
    #1%
  \else%
    \zeroTemplate{0#1}{#2}%
  \fi%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{luacode*}
  function createNodeText(idx, text)
    if idx>0 then
      tex.sprint(string.sub(text, 1, idx))
    end
    if idx <= string.len(text) then
      tex.sprint("\\makebox[0pt]{|}")
    end
  end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\animText{"Hello World!"}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% write timeline file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multido}
\newwrite\OutFile
\immediate\openout\OutFile=timeline.txt
\immediate\write\OutFile{::0:window.alert("This is the beginning of the animation.")}
\multido{\iFrame=1+1}{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len(\animText))}}{
  \immediate\write\OutFile{::\iFrame}
}
\multido{}{4}{
  \immediate\write\OutFile{::\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len(\animText))}}
}
\immediate\write\OutFile{::\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len(\animText))}:document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+2}}.svg')}
\immediate\closeout\OutFile
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[c]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,timeline=timeline.txt]{5}
         \multiframe{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len(\animText)+1)}}{idx=0+1}{
           \begin{tikzpicture}
             \useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2.5)rectangle++(5,5);
             \fill[green](-2.5,-2.5)rectangle++(5,5);
             \node[font=\Huge] at (0,0){\strut\directlua{createNodeText(\idx, \animText)}};
           \end{tikzpicture}
         }
      \end{animateinline}
    \end{center}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    After the animation ended, the next beamer frame is automatically loaded. 
  \end{frame}
\end{document}


Thank you very much for your answer! It is very informative. So basically, from the way the example you have shown works, is it correct to assume one can only access the properties via JavaScript in a timeline file and not - for instance - in a html website context/the debugging console of the browser?

To rephrase the question: Everything in explained in the animate manual, section 7  works only in the timeline file and due to the way animate creates the svg cannot be accessed as an svg attribute afterwards?

In PDF, at least, the animation can be controlled from outside via the anim[<label>] object, see this example in the manual. I need to try what is possible from SVG outside the animation, and further from HTML where the animated SVG is embedded in an <iframe> or <object> tag.

@dsacre The SVG's DOM including the animation object with its methods and properties is fully accessible from the parent document's JavaScript. See updated answer.

Thank you very much for your excellent examples; especially the last one with the <iframe>, which is exactly what I was looking for. Seems like I made an error in my original JavaScript (probably not setting the variable properly in the load state).

Yeah, it took me a little while too to find out that initialising the anim reference must be done in the onload event handler of the parent. Learned something new myself :)

Ok, so it was even to you not obvious (sigh of relief :-) May I share a link to the finished project (if I can get it to work, it is only thanks to your efforts) via your animate package's maintainer e-mail address?  From what you have shared on your GitLab, I think you might like it.

Thank you! Yes, it would be interesting to see what you have done.
